# Worst choice to mitigate overfitting

Tags: self-study, classification, overfitting, train

Here's a multiple choice question that was asked at an exam.

You are tuning a linear classifier that you suspect is overfitting the data. Which of the following choice is most likely to aggravate the overfitting ?

1. Increasing the number of features
2. Decreasing the number of features
3. Applying a stronger regularization on the features
4. Obtaining more data points
5. Using k-fold cross validation

Here are my thoughts.
3 is a well-known solution to overfitting. 5 is the go-to method for hyperparameter tuning, it should not interfere with the overfitting. 4 is always good and should reduce the overfitting.

Since the model is already overfitting, I suspect that adding more features on top of the existing ones will just make the overfitting worse. Hence I would go for Answer 1.
Can someone confirm that my reasoning makes sense ?

Comment: That is good reasoning, see also "curse of dimensionality". (your title question includes "mitigate" while your question in the body includes "aggravate", this can be confusing)

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776333/why-too-many-features-cause-over-fitting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thoughts are on point.

3. regularization is usually done precisely to avoid overfitting, to penalize complex models,
4. more data is usually good news, better estimates and more confidence (if the data is good),
5. k-fold is used to select a model, and usually you select the best model out of the set, so this should at the very least improve the situation.

What remains are points 1. and 2. which are about features.

It is a known fact that increasing the number of features makes model training harder and more unstable (see "curse of dimensionality"). The more variables you put in a model the more likely you are to find a random association between variables. Another potential issue specifically with linear models is high correlation between variables, which make the model estimates unstable.